# findall() returns only one result

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am trying to extract text between two words including the words that set the boundary using findall().

```
description = 'White cat sat on the mat and then the cat ran away'
starting_word = 'cat'
ending_word = 'ran'

detail_re = r'{0}.*?{1}'.format(starting_word, ending_word)
extracted_text_list = re.findall(detail_re, description,re.IGNORECASE)
```

Expected result:

> ['cat sat on the mat and then the cat ran', 'cat ran']

However, the result is:

> ['cat sat on the mat and then the cat ran']

How can I get the expected answer?

Comment: That is the expected answer. There's only one match to the *detail_re* in your *description* str.
If you're wanting to capture the beginning part you need to have r'\*?{0}.*?{1}'

Comment: Shorter example (oneliner): `re.findall('cat.*?ran', 'White cat sat on the mat and then the cat ran away')`

Comment: How could the first item in your expected results possibly be a match?  It doesn't start with "cat".

Comment: Try `detail_re = r'(.*\b({0})\b.*?\b({1})\b)'.format(starting_word, ending_word)`

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum this regular expression throws an error 're.error: nothing to repeat at position 0'. I am expecting ['cat sat on the mat and then the cat ran', 'cat ran']

Comment: @nrspider Forgot to add the period. Should be  r'.\*?{0}.\*?{1}'. Didn't realize you edited your expected result. Ignore the regex suggestion. It will still only return one match because you only have one word *ran*, so it can only match once. If you change your description to `description = 'White cat sat on the mat and then the ran cat ran away'`, you can see how it will now match twice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your response. But it returns [('White cat sat on the mat and then the cat ran', 'cat', 'ran')]

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum I have edited the expected answer (removed 'white' from the results). My concern is about extracting overlapping results, so there can be two results

Comment: Good, so the best you can do is `detail_re = r'\b(({0})\b.*?\b({1}))\b'.format(starting_word, ending_word)`. You cannot put disjoint texts into one group.

Comment: This works:

`import re`
`description = 'White cat sat on the mat and then the cat ran away'`
`detail_re = r'(?=(cat.*?ran))'`
`matches = re.finditer(detail_re, description)`
`extracted_text_list = [match.group(1) for match in matches]`
`print(extracted_text_list)`

Comment: Use look ahead assertion.  `detail_re = r'(?=({0}.*?{1}))'.format(starting_word, ending_word)` . The rest of the code is fine.

Comment: Correct answer has been provided by @mrin9san. There are two ways to do that.

Method 1: Using re 
detail_re = r'(?=({0}.*?{1}))'.format(starting_word, ending_word)
extracted_text_list = re.findall(detail_re, description,re.IGNORECASE)

Method 2: Using regex
detail_re = regex.compile(r'{0}.*?{1}'.format(starting_word, ending_word))
extracted_text_list = detail_re.findall(description,overlapped = True)

Method 2 cannot have re.IGNORECASE